# Why does the mersenne_twister_engine guarantee certain results?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I note the following on [cppreference's article for `std::mersenne_twister_engine`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) (e.g. `std::mt19937`):

> The 10000th consecutive invocation of a default-constructed `std::mt19937` is required to produce the value `4123659995`.
>
> The 10000th consecutive invocation of a default-constructed `std::mt19937_64` is required to produce the value `9981545732273789042`.

Assuming that this interpretation of the standard is accurate, what's the deal? Why do these guarantees exist? Isn't this *non-random*?

Comment: These are deterministic pseudo-random number generators. Without a proper randomized seed isn't that how they're going to behave? Seeding with an [actually random number](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) gives you  unpredictable output.

Comment: mersenne_twister is by definition non-random. Its a PRNG and I assume the requirement is to force the MT to have the correct implementation.

Comment: And to be reproducible, that's what is required in some domains.

Comment: Default seed or no, this seems like a very specific guarantee for the standard to make. I suppose I can understand if it's this "forcing it to have the correct implementation" but picking one particular datapoint is a weird way to go about that, no? Why not just say "this must abide by _such and such a standard_"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Um. There is a paper but no standard.

Comment: @Swordfish "this must abide by _such and such a mechanism documented in such and such a manner_"*

Comment: The sad thing is that the *reproducibility* goes out of the window for most tasks because the Standard does not make a similar guarantee for `std::uniform_int_distribution`. So, in a practical setting, different platforms produce different results :(

Comment: To be clear I realise that a PRNG isn't a RNG but this just seems so arbitrary. Obviously I'm missing something, hence the question ;)

Comment: Is the question more why pick the 10,000th number vs why specify that the default mt19937 use a specific seed?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Its just making sure every implementation does the same  as the original that has been measured to produce certain characteristics to a certain degree of probability.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The only reference I've found so far is wg21 paper [N1398](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1398.html). It has some rationale for 10,000 and specific values for several random engines.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't see that ([rand.predef](http://eel.is/c++draft/rand.predef)) at first.

Comment: @NathanOliver A bit of both, I think? I don't know.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Ah, that's interesting. So perhaps these are QoI "waypoints" that appear arbitrary in the standard text but are in fact based in what amounts to "prior research" from the source material. That would seem to be it. IMO a _[Note: ... -end note]_ is in order but perhaps that's just me.

Comment: The state transition and the generation algorithms are laid out in the standard. The requirement that the algo produces some specific numbers is just there to make double-sure, i guess.

Comment: If you picked the number `3` I guess there are a very large number of bad implementations that could fulfil the requirements. So they probably picked `10000` because it has `n^10000` less chance of being an incorrect implementation if it meets that guarantee?

Comment: Thanks @Blastfurnace; I stole your answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the proposal, [N1398](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1398.html):

> How can a user have confidence that the implementation of a random-number engine is exactly as specified, correctly taking into account any platform pecularities *[sic]* (e.g., odd-sized ints)? After all, minor typos in the implementation might not be apparent; the numbers produced may look "random". This proposal therefore specifies for each engine the 10000th number in the random number sequence that a default-constructed engine object produces.

So it's just a relatively arbitrary "waypoint", chosen as a way to ensure compliance of the implementation to the semantics of this PRNG.

It's not a semantic *constraint* per se; it's a *verification* that the implementation abides by the requirements.

IMO a note in the standard text might be in order, seeing as this is an unprecedented way to double-check quality of implementation. (I'm not aware of any other feature whose implementation's QoI may be verified by sample data given in the standard text itself.)

<sub>Credit is due to [Blastfurnace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445976/blastfurnace) for [first arriving at this notion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876332/why-does-the-mersenne-twister-engine-guarantee-certain-results#comment96522966_54876332).</sub>

Comment: Arguably, this is no different than the sections in the spec that say "such and such syntax should have these post-condtitions" and "such and such syntax should emit a diagnostic"

Comment: @MooingDuck Perhaps but it's so "unit-test-like"; I can't think of any other example that involves concrete datapoints, at least not one that doesn't explain why it's there or one that isn't normative. I don't have a problem with it, but that was the cause of my not knowing what the heck was going on

Answer (score 3):

All technical useful random number generators are **pseudo**-random generators ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator)) by design. This means they have a seed, and produce 100% identical sequences based on a given seed. This is a critical requirement for application in Monte Carlo simulations, etc., where you can run into rare problems or bugs, and without this feature it would be impossible to develop any stable complex Monte Carlo simulation sequence.

So random numbers do NOT produce random numbers. They produce sequences of numbers that have zero correlation over any or very long distance.

In your example, default initialization just correspond to one particular of such sequences.